# phpMyAdmin asks for BasicAuth

Tags: .htaccess, http-basic-authentication, phpmyadmin, htpasswd

When accessing the phpMyAdmin link (`mydomain.com/phpMyAdmin/`), I am being prompted with a BasicAuth pop-up.

The `phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php` does not overwrite any defaults, therefore the `config.default.php` is used, which has `auth_type` set as `cookie`.

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
```

There's no `.htaccess` file in my phpMyAdmin, nor an entry in `httpd.conf` pointing to the phpMyAdmin folder.

The overall Directory entry in `httpd.conf` looks like this:

```
<Directory "/var/www/home">
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

If I add a `.htpasswd` inside the phpMyAdmin folder, entering the there stored user and password lets me get to the phpMyAdmin page.

The thing is that I would like to have a single `.htpasswd` outside the www folder, however even if I add a `.htaccess` file pointing to the outside `.htpasswd` file, it's still asking me for the user/pass from the inside-phpMyAdmin `.htpasswd` file.

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Authentication Required"
AuthUserFile "/etc/htpasswd/.htpasswd"
Require valid-user
```

Creating a new empty folder, say phpMyAdmin2, `.htaccess` works as expected for that folder. Thus I suppose it has something to do with phpMyAdmin?!

**Why when accessing the phpMyAdmin link I am prompted for a BasicAuth? How can I find where is that configured?**

Comment: AFAIK the "AuthName" has to be identical to get it working.

Comment: With what should it be identical? The `AuthName` only appears in `/var/www/home/phpMyAdmin/.htaccess`, or is there another place where I should set that?

Comment: If you have two .htaccess files at different parts of the tree, they need to have the same AuthName to be treated as same.

Comment: Aha, I understand. From the official docs: `The AuthName directive sets the Realm to be used in the authentication. The realm serves two major functions. First, the client often presents this information to the user as part of the password dialog box. Second, it is used by the client to determine what password to send for a given authenticated area.` However that's not the cause of the problem above.